# Drywalling or hiding 4" plumbing pipe through wall

Tags: plumbing, drywall

I've got a 4" plumbing pipe coming out the side of a wall at about eye-level. Historically it had some messy hot-mud up to the pipe, sanded smooth-ish but it didn't look great. The pipe had to be replaced (from rust) and now I've got a big gap around the pipe on a small thin wall.

[image: pipe through wall]

Looking for advice, I could do my best mudding around it with mesh tape. I am wondering if there is a 4" plastic or rubber flange escutcheon type thing that will make my life easier. Its very close to the back wall, so its pretty difficult to mud closely.

Comment: "Its very close to the back wall" is why you can't use an escutcheon, and also where it doesn't matter how bad it is. Sanding there is hard so don't go crazy with the coats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**4" plastic escutcheon**

gets results in a search engine - some of them are 4" OD and won't work for you - others include 4" ID and will.

Since directing you to any particular result would be a matter of shopping for you, which is off-topic, the question of existence being solved, you can go find some yourself. You may have to trim the side against the wall that's close to the pipe.

I would advise doing at least a crude mud job first, having seen rodents use escutcheon gaps as highways. You could also box in the whole pipe if the bare pipe against the wall does not suit the decorative motif.

Comment: Maybe some b-vent fittings.  But no... mesh tape and mud +1. "thing that will make my life easier" = newspaper in the hole first.